# AJAX In Wordpress returns 0

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to get my ajax request to work but only get returned 0;
not sure exactly why i'm not getting a response back. I dont really fully understand how the my_ajax_pagination() function handles. I was just finding other solutions online and found something like that.

```
$(document).on( 'click', 'polygon', function( event ) {

 var county = $(this).attr('id')
 var region = $(this).closest('a').data('region');
    jQuery.ajax(
        {
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajaxpagination.ajaxurl,
                dataType:'json',
                        data: {
                                    action: 'my_ajax_pagination',

                                },

            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            },
                        error:function(err){
                            console.log('err')
                        }
        });
    })
})(jQuery);
```

functions.php

```
            function my_enqueue_assets() {
                wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
                wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-pagination',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax-pagination.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );

                    global $wp_query;

                    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-pagination', 'ajaxpagination', array(
                        'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
                        'query_vars' => json_encode( $wp_query->query ),
                      'serurity' => wp_create_nonce('wp-admin-order')
                    ));
            };

            function my_ajax_pagination() {
              $query_vars = json_decode( stripslashes( $_POST['query_vars'] ), true );
              $query_vars['county'] = $_POST['county'];
              $query_vars['region'] = $_POST['region'];

                $query = new WP_Query( array(
                        'post_type' => 'resource',
                        'posts_per_page'=> -1
                ) );
                echo $query_vars;
                die();
            };
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_pagination', 'my_ajax_pagination' );
        add_action( 'wp_ajax__ajax_pagination', 'my_ajax_pagination' );
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting 0 is that no function is called in WordPress. The action that you send to ajax should be `ajax_pagination` and not `my_ajax_pagination`, the action should be the same name as `wp_ajax_{name}`.